# Is it possible to prevent g++ from pushing epb and saving esp at the start of a function across optimization levels?

Tags: c++, g++

Consider the following code, which I will throw into a file called `Epb.cc`.

```
void f() {       
    asm("nop");  
}
```

Now, I compile it under a variety of optimization levels.

```
g++ -c -O0 -o Out0 Ebp.cc
g++ -c -O1 -o Out1 Ebp.cc
g++ -c -O2 -o Out2 Ebp.cc
g++ -c -O3 -o Out3 Ebp.cc
```

Here is the output of `objdump -d` on each one.

```
$ objdump -d Out*                               

Out0:     file format elf64-x86-64              


Disassembly of section .text:                   

0000000000000000 <_Z1fv>:                       
   0:   55                      push   %rbp     
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   90                      nop             
   5:   5d                      pop    %rbp     
   6:   c3                      retq            

Out1:     file format elf64-x86-64              


Disassembly of section .text:                   

0000000000000000 <_Z1fv>:                       
   0:   90                      nop             
   1:   c3                      retq            

Out2:     file format elf64-x86-64              


Disassembly of section .text:                   

0000000000000000 <_Z1fv>:                       
   0:   90                      nop             
   1:   c3                      retq            

Out3:     file format elf64-x86-64              


Disassembly of section .text:                   

0000000000000000 <_Z1fv>:                       
   0:   90                      nop             
   1:   c3                      retq
```

**Is it possible to instruct `g++` to not add the three extra instructions for this particular function across all optimization levels?**

Comment: @MichaelPetch, This does solve the problem, so I will accept this as an answer. I was looking for something that can affect a single function only, but I think this will work just as well.

Comment: Actually I removed the comment almost right after posting it since I realized you were really looking for a function level way to do it. With GCC/G++ I'm unsure there is a function attribute that does it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch, I think the comment will still be valuable to anyone who looks at this question in the future, even if there is no function-level way to do it.

Comment: I think there have been similar question, but if you wish to self answer your question with my solution please feel free to do so.

Comment: I know this probably isn't the answer you want, but let me make a plea for NOT using inline asm.  If you are going to have an actual function (ie call/ret), you might as well use an actual asm routine.  This allows you 100% control over what goes in the routine.  And there are [other](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) reasons.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd, I appreciate the comment, and I will strongly consider moving my code into an actual asm routine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @MichaelPetch pointed out in a comment, one solution that will affect this function (but also other functions in addition) is to use the `-fomit-frame-pointer` compiler option, which will cause `g++` to omit the prologue whenever it finds the opportunity to, regardless of optimization level.